# Condition between two join in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables and i want to join two of them with a condition.

For exemple if i have table A, table B and Table C, i'd like to have JOIN AB or JOIN BC.

Does something like this exists ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM B
(JOIN A
ON (B.b=A.id_a) 
OR (B.b=A.id_b))
OR
(JOIN C
ON (B.b=C.id_a)
OR (B.b=C.id_b))
WHERE B.a=1001485422
```

Comment: Under what condition do you join with A versus joining with C?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both joins at once

```
select *
from
    b
    left join
    a on b.b in (a.id_a, a.id_b)
    left join
    c on b.b in (c.id_a, c.id_b)
where b.a = 1001485422
```

Comment: Sorry but here it seems that both join will be applied and i just want one of them.. :/

Comment: @user3750255 Which of them? What is the condition?

Comment: I would like to execute just one JOIN and ignore the false one.

Like "SELECT * FROM a (join b on ...)OR(join c on ...) WHERE ....

Comment: @user3750255 Which one is the false one? What is the test?